# Is it possible to use Mac Mail with MS Exchange if IMAP is disabled

Tags: exchange-server, apple-mail

Our network admins have disabled IMAP and POP for our exchange server, but do have RDP over HTTP enabled.  Does Mac Mail only use IMAP to communicate with exchange servers, or does it also know how to use RDP over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Mac mail uses IMAP for mail and uses HTTP to fetch calendar data, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

No. Mail.app supports IMAP and POP, but no RDP over HTTP, yet.